# 2D array as return value c++

Tags: c++

I want to build a function which returns a 2D array

```
TExposureType** CAteImage::GetExposureMatrix()
{
       TExposureType** ptr =  new TExposureType*[FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS];
       for (int i = 0; i < FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS; i++)
       {
              ptr[i] = new TExposureType[FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS];
              for (int j = 0; j < FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS; j++)
              {
                     ptr[i][j] = m_ExposureMatrix[i][j];
              }
       }
       return ptr;
}
```

I know my code isn't effective - i can do the same with with a single malloc + 1 memcpy.

I can't however figure how to return the member i have  m_ExposureMatrix[i][j] as a const ref?

```
TExposureType   m_ExposureMatrix[FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS][FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS];
```

Comment: Your code is returning a pointer to an array of arrays, so a 2D array. What exactly do you want?

Comment: A pointer-to-pointer is, syntactic sugar aside, *not* a 2D array. A 2D array is `arr[N][M]` and is *not* the same.

Comment: to know how to return a reference instead of a pointer for a 2D array

Comment: A reference to *what* ?? Your dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @WhozCraig i want to return a 2D array like m_ExposureMatrix[i][j]; as a const ref from my function. can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: no a ref to my member m_ExposureMatrix[i][j]

Comment: What is the **type** of `m_ExposureMatrix` ?

Comment: TExposureType m_ExposureMatrix[FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS][FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS], you can consider it as an int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your question correctly, (and that's a big if), this is what you want:

In your class header:

```
const TExposureType (&GetExposureMatrix()) [FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS][FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS];
```

and in your cpp file

```
const TExposureType (&CAteImage::GetExposureMatrix()) [FORMAT_MATRIX_COLS][FORMAT_MATRIX_ROWS]
{
    return m_ExposureMatrix;
};
```

You can significantly shorten this up with `decltype` if you have a compliant compiler that supports it, btw. Either way, you should be able to return `m_ExposureMatrix` by const-reference doing the above.